# Ioredis query is timing out only on my local machine

Tags: next.js, redis

Working in a Next.js project that serves a site.  Am running a function in getStaticProps that queries a redis instance in Upstash for some data that is needed.  Everything works really well in production, but for some reason, one day, the function started timing out to various degrees of length.  Sometimes it would time out a couple times and then was successful in connecting; other times it would reach the max amount of timeouts.  This is not happening for anyone else on my team when they spin up the same site.  Everything works well for them, just like production.

I have not changed any network settings on my local, and my internet connection is quite fast.  I have had no luck finding any threads on this kind of a problem and why I'm having this connection problem.  I have no other similar issues with my machine.  If anyone has any light to shed on this, it would be much appreciated!